# Nginx Docker stuck at "Configuration complete; ready for start up" after copying custom config

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to run a Docker image on a container, here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
```

When I remove the line that copies the nginx.conf into the image, it works:

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I've already used the nginx default config and the problem persists, so the problem isn't my config file I think.

```
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    server {
        location /api {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_pass http://#removed_for_privacy#;
        }

        location /socket.io/ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass #removed_for_privacy#;
        }

        location / {
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Nginx config file seems ok:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Any clues on this?

Comment: So when you say you've used the default config file, what exactly does that mean? You extracted the base image's `nginx.conf` file, added it to your local files and copied that over during the build and it too did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set ports on starting container?
And nginx show no signs of life.

> docker run -p 80:80 nginx